# Touch events are not working on Xiaomi and Vivo devices ,after adding view on window manager in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-view, android-windowmanager

I am working on edge lightning application in android , where I have to add view on Window Manger to give lighting effect across edges when enabled. In samsung and pixel devices it working fine , touch events inside and outside of application working fine , but when I try to test on Xiaomi and Vivo devices it is not working , touch events are not working, here is code to add view on Window Manger,

```
 val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(getRealSize().x, getRealSize().y, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE , PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT)
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP

            windowManager?.addViewOnWindows(binding.root, params),
```

I tried several flags, present in window manager which are as,
FLAG_FULLSCREEN
FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
FLAG_SECURE
FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED, and many more I have tried, but it is not working ,

from somewhere I have also find some random flag which is 824 , which is working better than remaing flags, but the xiaomi problem persists.

I have also attached videos where it is working and where it is not,

[Samsung device][Working example of samsung device.]
[Xiamoi device][Not Working in Xiaomi device.]

Comment: Samsung device ->https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M1AIJM0qRrHnbJefhM-r1uEtxJ1Cqp6o/view?usp=share_link
xiaomi device->[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mdwEf-TynyUeEzI3kmNj86eOXc4y5E9Z/view?usp=share_link)